# google drive api python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to write a desktop python app using google drive API but the documentation on google website is a little messy and twisted with drive sdk which makes thing complicated and difficult to find useful staffs.
Can anyone give some useful doc and some sample code?
Thx~

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? A complete Python sample is available at https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python

Answer (score 0):

When using Twisted, you will need to adopt a policy whereby every Drive API call is deferred to a thread or threadPool. I recently wrote a blog post about it here:

http://unpythonic.blogspot.com/2012/07/calling-google-drive-api-and-other.html